# Gradle: Create a jar with no classes, only resources

Tags: java, jar, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to create a group of four jars with the following pattern (each jar has its own project.  `helpRootDir` is shared between all four jars.  If somebody knows of a way to make one task that does all four, that'd be awesome)

```
def helpRootDir = 'runtime/datafiles/help/'
project(':schedwinclihelp') {
    def helpDir = 'schedwincli'

    //Include no classes.  This is strictly a resource jar
    sourceSets.main.java {
        exclude 'com/**'
    }

    jar {
        from '${helpRootDir}/${helpDir}'
        include '**/*.*'
    }

}
```

Anyway as you can see from the above, I want no classes in the jar, and that's working.  Unfortunately, all I'm actually getting in the jar is a MANIFEST.MF file.  None of the files in the jar definition are getting added.  I want the full file tree in `${helpRootDir}/${helpDir}` added to the root of the jar.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out I was referencing my variables incorrectly.

The correct syntax is:

```
def helpRootDir = 'runtime/datafiles/help/'
project(':schedwinclihelp') {
    def helpDir = 'schedwincli'

    //Include no classes.  This is strictly a resource jar
    sourceSets.main {
        java {
            exclude 'com/**'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir  helpRootDir + '/' + helpDir
        }
    }
}
```

Note `srcDir  helpRootDir + '/' + helpDir` rather than `'${helpRootDir}/${helpDir}'`.  Also, I just made my help dir a resource dir and let the java plugin do its thing automatically.

Comment: is this still the correct way to add resources to jar with gradle?

Comment: TBH I'm using maven in my current job, haven't touched Gradle in several years.  I'd recommend posting a new question if this isn't working for your use case

Answer (score 1):

The following task will create a JAR file named `resources.jar` with main resource files only (those are placed under `src/main/resoures` directory).

Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
tasks {
    task<Jar>("resourcesJar") {
        from(sourceSets["main"].resources)
        archiveFileName.set("resources.jar")
    }
}
```

Groovy DSL:

```
tasks.create("resourcesJar", Jar.class) {
    from sourceSets.main.resources
    archiveFileName = "resources.jar"
}
```